How to save survey designed dataset for other analysis (preferred R)
Is there any way to save weighted survey with strata and fpc as dataframe? For example, here is the simple dataframe:
Data <- data.frame(
  X =c(1,4,6,4,1,7,3,2,2),
  Y = c(6,5,9,9,43,65,45,67,90),
  weight = c(0.1,1.2,4,0,0,5,0.65,1,0)
  )

Using the survey package to include the weight variable.
library(survey)
dat_weight <- svydesign(ids = ~1, data = Data, weights = Data$weight)

I would like to save this object (dat_weight) as a simple dataframe and use/export it for other analyses (such as latent variable modeling, and so on). Can I ask is it possible to do that?
I am struggling to figure out do some more complex analysis using other packages, such as growth modeling, pca, etc.

Your dat_weight is an R object with class survey.design. It's not a "simple data frame" (although it contains the original data frame within). Your question should probably focus on your further analysis downstream.

df <- data.frame(dat_weight$variables, cluster_id = dat_weight$cluster$id, prob = dat_weight$prob) will return information from your survey object, but as it is not clear how you intend to use it, I can't say if this is the best approach or not.

This vignette from the srvyr package may be helpful.

@Edward Thanks for that. I was also thinking about this, the object created by svydesign() actually is a design. I am new to this topic working with complex survey data and may be not able to describe my question very well. My question is mainly to wonder if there will be possible to conduct other analysis after setting the survey design, such as latent variable modeling, sem, growth modeling, etc, as I felt like there aren't very much existing softwares supported for different kinds of analysis based on complex survey data. Most are basically designed for using data based on simple samping.

@LTyrone Thanks! I want to conduct some analysis such as growth modeling, sem, etc, while the data was collected based on stratification and clustering sampling design. I am just thinking about there will do more work before conducting these analysis and i am figuring out how to do these... Hope to find some ways to do  that.

here's a commented-out example of how to save a data.frame object.  you could use saveRDS() on either the acs_df or the acs_design objects, depending on which you want to be the savepoint
https://asdfree.com/american-community-survey-acs.html#save-locally
